# Open app with data or URL if not exist iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I want to make an app that reads a ndef formatted NFC tag. It should read a key that then the app uses to identify a person.

If the app is not installed it should open a website or play store instead.

I need the same functionality for iOS and Android. Is this possible? If not, what would happen if the app is not installed.

Planning to develop the apps using Flutter but might be easier just making a mobile website and pass the key as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Appsflyer if you are willing to use a paid solution. Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48437267/5493999)