# Expo - Android App Link dynamicly redirect to play store if app not installed

Tags: react-native, expo, google-play, deep-linking, android-app-links

I'm trying to redirect a user which scan a QRCode ( or click a link ) to

- my app

**OR**

- if he doesn't have the app redirected him to the play store on my app's details page.

I've found out [Firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links) but unfortunately they're being deprecated ( in 2025 tho ) but I shouldn't go in that direction.

I've read a lot about [Android App Link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) but as far as I understood ... They don't provide such a feature.

I've found this ["Hacky solution"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48437267/3636091) which suggest to have a server which redirects back to the market link ( `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<bundleName>` ). This should work because if the user already has the app it would open it before the web browser ... But (again as far as I understood) this need to host a web page with a `<redirect>` meta tag ?

Is is possible to achieve that without hosting a server ?