How to redirect to Play store using App Links if app not installed in Android?
I am using the concept of deep linking in my app & have to integrate deep linking tool without any pricing. for this i am using App links in Android and successfully able to integrate it as well
when i share the link from my app its working fine it goes to the destination in app
but problem is when a user is not having app installed this link is opening through phone's browser and error is displayed of not found but i want to go to the play store if app is not installed. what approach should i try.
or please suggest any free 3rd party tool to implement the same functionality
Thanks in advance!!

See this my friend : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436575/deep-linking-to-redirect-to-play-store-if-app-not-installed?rq=2
